# How to extract data using regular expressions?

Tags: grep

> **crawl-66-249-64-13.hero.com** - - [**17/Oct/2004:04:40:15** +0100] "GET /**rubbish.txt** HTTP/1.0" **200 25** "-" "Hero/2.1
>   (+http://www.Hero.com/rub.html)"

The bits in bold are the parts I want to extract

I currently have

```
"^(.*) - .* \["
```

I am using regular expressions in grep anyone have any ideas? I am using a bash script
I know awk is a good way to do it but I want it in a table not just printed

Comment: Do you need a bash script or a php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
var='crawl-66-249-64-13.hero.com - - [17/Oct/2004:04:40:15 +0100] "GET /rubbish.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 25 "-" "Hero/2.1 (+http://www.Hero.com/rub.html)"'
echo "${var}" | \
    sed -e 's/^\([-a-zA-Z0-9.]*\)\( - - \[\)\([A-Za-z0-9\/:]*\)\(.*GET \/\)\([A-Za-z0-9.]*\)\(.*" \)\([0-9]* [0-9]*\)\( .*\)/\1\t\3\t\5\t\7/g'
```

Not pretty but works :)

```
Output: crawl-66-249-64-13.hero.com 17/Oct/2004:04:40:15    rubbish.txt 200 25
```

Basically you have to break it up into the chunks you want, and then only output what you want.  The "\1" in the sed command will display the first matched section.  The \t is to add a tab between them.  Change to what ever you would like.  You want to match for items from 8 chunks.. which is why the output is \1\3\5\7